# Detecting multiply forms on one image

Tags: python, keras

I made a convolutional neural network, have trained the model, and now it can accurately determine the form that is on the photo.

But now I need to make sure that it determines all the forms that are in one photo. So I need to somehow cut the original photo into parts, and then identify each.

What is the best way to do it? I am using Python3, keras. Learning and recognition code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import pickle
import cv2
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import load_model
from imutils import paths


matplotlib.use ("Agg")

categories = ['bread', 'chicken', 'cucumbers', 'dry_peas', 'eggs',
              'green_peas', 'kolbasa', 'potato', 'raw_beef',
              'spaghetti', 'tomatoes']

dataset = "ingredients"
model_path = "test_model.model"
label_bin = "test_model.pickle"
plot = "output / test_model_plot.png"

print ("[INFO] loading images ...")
data = []
labels = []

imagePaths = sorted (list (paths.list_images (dataset)))
random.seed (42)
random.shuffle (imagePaths)

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    try:
        image = cv2.imread (imagePath)
        image = cv2.resize (image, (32, 32))
        data.append (image / 255)

        label = imagePath.split (os.path.sep) [- 2]
        labels.append (categories.index (label))
    except Exception as e:
        print ("[WARNING]", e)

data = np.array (data)
print (labels)
labels = to_categorical (np.array (labels))
print (labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split (data, labels,
                                                  test_size = 0.2,
                                                  random_state = 42)

lb = LabelBinarizer ()
trainY = lb.fit_transform (trainY)
testY = lb.transform (testY)
'' '
model = Sequential ()
model.add (Conv2D (32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (32, 32, 3)))
model.add (MaxPooling2D ((2, 2)))
model.add (Conv2D (64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add (MaxPooling2D ((2, 2)))
model.add (Flatten ())
model.add (Dropout (0.5))
model.add (Dense (512, activation = "sigmoid"))
model.add (Dense (len (lb.classes_), activation = "softmax"))
'' '
model = load_model ('test_model.model')

INIT_LR = 0.01
EPOCHS = 150

print ("[INFO] training network ...")
opt = SGD (lr = INIT_LR)
model.compile (loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt,
              metrics = ["accuracy"])

H = model.fit (trainX, trainY, validation_data = (testX, testY),
              epochs = EPOCHS, batch_size = 32)

print ("[INFO] evaluating network ...")
predictions = model.predict (testX, batch_size = 32)
print (predictions)
#print (classification_report (testY.argmax (axis = 1)
# predictions.argmax (axis = 1), target_names = lb.classes_))

N = np.arange (0, EPOCHS)
plt.style.use ("ggplot")
plt.figure ()
print (H.history.keys ())
plt.plot (N, H.history ["loss"], label = "train_loss")
plt.plot (N, H.history ["val_loss"], label = "val_loss")
plt.plot (N, H.history ["accuracy"], label = "train_acc")
plt.plot (N, H.history ["val_accuracy"], label = "val_acc")
plt.title ("Training Loss and Accuracy (Simple NN)")
plt.xlabel ("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel ("Loss / Accuracy")
plt.legend ()
plt.savefig (plot)

print ("[INFO] serializing network and label binarizer ...")
model.save (model_path)
f = open (label_bin, "wb")
f.write (pickle.dumps (lb))
f.close ()
```

and

```
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
import flask
import werkzeug
from keras.models import load_model
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as tb
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

import sys
sys.modules['keras'] = keras

class FoodRecognizer:
    def __init__(self, model, label_bin, size, flatten):
        self.label_bin = label_bin
        self.size = size
        self.width, self.height = self.size
        self.flatten = flatten

        print("[INFO] loading network and label binarizer...")
        set_session(sess)
        self.model = load_model(model)
        self.lb = pickle.loads(open(self.label_bin, "rb").read())

    def load_image(self, image_file):
        image = cv2.imread(image_file)
        output = image.copy()
        image = cv2.resize(image, self.size)
        image = image / 255.0
        image = image.reshape(1, *image.shape)

        self.image = image

    def recognize(self):
        preds = self.model.predict(self.image)
        result = list(preds[0])

        for i in range(len(result)):
            print(categories[i].ljust(10, " "), result[i], sep='\t')

        i = preds.argmax(axis=1)[0]

        print()

        out = sorted(result)[-3:][::-1]
        print("Скорее всего, на фотографии:")
        for o in out:
            print(categories[result.index(o)], f"{round(o * 100, 2)}%")

        label = self.lb.classes_[i]

        return label


app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    print(flask.request.files.to_dict())
    imagefile = flask.request.files['image']

    filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
    print("\nReceived image File name : " + imagefile.filename)
    imagefile.save('images/' + str(filename))

    MFR.load_image('images/' + filename)
    print(MFR.image)
    print('images/' + filename)

    with graph.as_default():
        set_session(sess)
        result = MFR.recognize()
    print(result)

    return categories[result]


categories = ['bread', 'chicken', 'cucumbers', 'dry_peas', 'eggs',
              'green_peas', 'kolbasa', 'potato', 'raw_beef',
              'spaghetti', 'tomatoes']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model_path = "test_model.model"
    label_path = "test_model.pickle"

    size = (32, 32)
    flatten = 1

    sess = tf.Session()
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    MFR = FoodRecognizer(model_path, label_path, size, flatten)

    #MFR.load_image("images/test_image.jpg")
    #print(categories[MFR.recognize()])

    set_session(sess)

    app.run(host='10.61.4.238', debug=True, threaded=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are refering to image segmentation, check out [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-semantic-segmentation-with-unet-6be4f42d4b47) article to find out more information.

In short, it is similar to classification but instead of giving one class it draws bounding boxes around the detected objects.